plumber API deploy from Posit Workbench to Posit Connect authentication failure
I have a simple R plumber API which I created and tested on Posit Workbench and want to deploy on Posit Connect. In Connect, there is an authentication failure because after authorization in Swagger, the req$HTTP_AUTHORIZATION is apparently still empty:
picture curl
The code:
library(plumber)
library(stringr)
library(base64enc)
library(jsonlite)

# Function to extract name and email from the text
extract_info <- function(text) {
  pattern <- "(?<=Voornaam:\\s)[A-Za-z]+|(?<=E-mail:\\s)[\\w.-]+@[\\w.-]+"
  matches <- str_extract_all(text, pattern)
  result <- unlist(matches)
  return(result)
}

# Basic Authentication
authenticate <- function(auth_header, username, password) {
  if (is.null(auth_header) || auth_header == "") {
    return(list(status = 401, body = list(error = "Authentication required")))
  }
  auth <- sub("Basic ", "", auth_header)
  decoded <- rawToChar(base64decode(auth))
  auth_parts <- strsplit(decoded, ":")[[1]]
  if (length(auth_parts) != 2 || auth_parts[1] != username || auth_parts[2] != password) {
    return(list(status = 401, body = list(error = "Invalid credentials")))
  }
  return(NULL)
}

#* @apiTitle extract_webinargeek
#* @apiDescription Plumber example description.

#* Extract name and email from text
#* @param text The input text containing the information.
#* @post /extract
function(req, res, text = "") {
  # Debugging output
  print(paste("Authorization header:", req$HTTP_AUTHORIZATION))
  
  # Authentication
  auth_header <- req$HTTP_AUTHORIZATION
  auth_error <- authenticate(auth_header, "username", "password")
  print(paste("auth_error:",auth_error))
  if (!is.null(auth_error)) {
    res$status <- auth_error$status
    print(paste("res_status:",res$status))
    return(auth_error$body)
  }
  
  # Process request
  result <- extract_info(text)
  if (length(result) == 2) {
    list(name = result[1], email = result[2])
  } else {
    list(error = "Invalid input format or missing required fields")
  }
}

# Add the authentication requirement to the API specification
add_basic_auth <- function(x, paths = NULL) {
  x[["components"]] <- list(
    securitySchemes = list(
      BasicAuth = list(
        type = "http",
        scheme = "basic"
      )
    )
  )
  if (is.null(paths)) paths <- names(x$paths)
  for (path in paths) {
    nn <- names(x$paths[[path]])
    for (p in intersect(nn, c("get", "head", "post", "put", "delete"))) {
      x$paths[[path]][[p]] <- c(
        x$paths[[path]][[p]],
        list(security = list(list(BasicAuth = vector())))
      )
    }
  }
  x
}

# Programmatically alter your API
#* @plumber
function(pr) {
  pr %>%
    # Overwrite the default serializer to return unboxed JSON
    pr_set_serializer(serializer_unboxed_json()) %>%
    pr_set_api_spec(add_basic_auth) # Add the authentication to the spec
}




So again: after authenticating in posit connect, I have a curl with Basic authorization string. However, I get response 401 Authorization required..
Does someone have experience in basic authentication in Posit Connect?
